# Android Activitys

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context

I have the code to display a menu drawer in DrawerClass class, this class is instantiated by all activitys to display the menu, the problem is that donot like handing the Intents of each menu the first parameter, it is usually "theActivity.this" , this clearly does not work when an external class, then as you get? I tried getAplicationContext, pass the context as a parameter to the class and nothing.

MainActivity

```
DrawerClass d=new DrawerClass();
d.crear(listado,getApplicationContext(),getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_home));
```

DrawerClass

```
    public void crear(ListView listado, final Context context, final String nom){    
    final ArrayList<String> datos=new ArrayList<String>();
    datos.add(nom);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(contexto,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,datos);
    listado.setAdapter(adapter);

    listado.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
          String valor=datos.get(position);
          if (valor.equals(nom)) {
              Intent home = new Intent(context, HomeActivity.class);
              startActivity(home);
         }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: have you tried only" **this**" orelse **getActivity()**?

Comment: if it returns nullpointer.

Comment: can you please post the complete class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the activity as parameter to the function `crear`:

MainActivity

```
DrawerClass d = new DrawerClass();
d.crear(listado, MainActivity.this,
        getResources().getString(R.string.title_activity_home));
```

DrawerClass

```
public void crear(ListView listado, final Activity activity, final String nom) {    

    final ArrayList<String> datos = new ArrayList<String>();
    datos.add(nom);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datos);
    listado.setAdapter(adapter);

    listado.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
          String valor = datos.get(position);
          if (valor.equals(nom)) {
              Intent home = new Intent(activity, HomeActivity.class);
              activity.startActivity(home);
         }
        }
    });
}
```